# One development server with Apache with multiple Virtual Host?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

Let's said that I will have a unique development server sharing code for multiple developers. The code for each developer will be on it's home directory under `sources` so basically it will be something like `~/<developer_name>/sources`. That server is running Apache 2.4.x.

I need that each developer could access their code by for example `<developer_name>.domain.com`. Off course the `developer_name` on the URL will match the name on the `/home` directory.

My solution is a Virtual Host per developer on the Apache config, is there any better solution and I am not aware?

Comment: [Dynamically Configured Mass Virtual Hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/mass.html) and a catch-all DNS record and the only thing you need to do is to create user accounts

Comment: @HBruijn thats' exactly what I want to achieve although I am a bit lost about catch-all DNS record, how? what do you mean by this? Sorry for my ignorance this is my first time trying to implement this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a similar setup.

The one catch is that you'll want to have a whole subdomain for your server.  So instead of jdoe.domain.com & bsmith.domain.com, you'll have jdoe.dev.domain.com and bsmith.dev.domain.com.  You can almost think of the 'dev.domain.com' as the server.

You'll probably want to do something like this:

**Apache module**

Make sure that the *vhost_alias* module is enabled.

```
# a2enmod vhost_alias
```

**Apache config**

(the key is the *VirtualDocumentRoot* directive)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName dev.domain.com
  ServerAlias dev.domain.com *.dev.domain.com
  VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%1/sources
</VirtualHost>
```

**DNS entry**

You need a DNS entry to point dev.domain.com and anything under it (*.dev.domain.com) to your development server.

If you want to get rid of the 'dev' subdomain, you'll have to make a DNS entry for every developer.

A BIND record in the domain.com zone could look like this:

```
*.dev     A       10.1.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them to have their own domain names? If not, there is the built-in mod_userdir that will do this. Your developers would be at http://developers.domain.com/~<developer_name>/ (such as /~bob/). You would just define UserDir to be "sources" (the default is public_html).

The config is usually in httpd.conf, but you'd just need something like:

```
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir sources
</IfModule>
```

You may also have a `UserDir disable` that you'll also have to comment out.

Comment: Sadly yes, the application work with licenses based on domains! but anyway is helpful too I have two ways to get it done now :)